# Magento CE Customer Groups Changing Not Saving

Tags: php, magento

In the Magento CE Admin Panel, I go to Customer > Manage Customers.

Then tick the select box in the customer row that I want to assign to a group, then in the 'actions' dropdown above I select 'Assign to a customer group' then select the group then click 'Submit'.

I then get a 'Total of 1 record(s) were updated' message displayed above but the problem is that my customer group still has not been updated/saved! No errors but not updating!

I even tried editing the customer group by editing the customer's account information 'Group' setting but same result?!

I have no idea how to resolve this...

Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Solved! I had to tick the 'Disable Automatic Group Change Based on VAT ID' box under customer group dropdown under the Account Information tab when you edit a particular customer's information. Easy peesey!

Answer (score 6):

Here the Customer's group is automatically updating due to VAT ID.So please select / check the check box of "Disable Automatic Group Change Based on VAT ID" under the "Group" select drop-down on edit customer's detail page "Account Information" tab.

Please share and comment if find helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is old thread but the issue was in Settings > Customers > Customer Configuration(in your admin panel) . Please set **Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group** to no.

Comment: This option being set to yes broke two things for me - selection of customer group in admin order and application of customer group specific price rules on the frontend - unfortunately I found this post after several hours of testing